# How remove() function was executed in python?

Tags: python, list

Actually I was working with this code:

```
m=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
for i in m:
    m.remove(i)
print(m)
```

This looks pretty simple.

```
for i in m:
      print(i)
```

will print every elements in the list m. So the **for** part in our code will extract every elements of the list and remove it one by one. So the output that I except is [].

But I got [1,3,5,7].

How it can be the output and where I was wrong?

Comment: You're iterating over a list which you are modifying as you traverse its contents. Try: *for i in m[:]:* and notice the difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know how to use a debugger, that would be the ideal way to diagnose this, otherwise, try running this code to see what's going on:

```py
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
for i in x.copy():
    x.remove(i)
    print(x)
print(x)


m = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
for i in m:
    m.remove(i)
    print(m)
print(m)
```

During a given execution, the for loop accesses an element and then deletes it. For example, it first deletes the element at index 0, with value 0, leaving you with `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`. Then it moves on to the element at index 1, value 2, and deletes that, leaving you with `[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`.

In general, avoid messing around with a list in Python. If you have to delete all elements, use `m.clear()`. If you have to delete some elements or do some other stuff, prefer to use [list comprehension](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/) to create a new object.

Comment: Actually if I iterate pop() I'll get that. In this case the remove function will take object as an argument and removes it. That's the most confusing part.

Comment: `pop()` acts on the index while `remove()` acts on the value. I'm not sure what you are doing, but if I just substitute `pop` for `remove` everywhere in my code, it eventually returns an error (as expected). Try using a list with different values from the index, like `[75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85]`.

Answer (score 2):

when you use (for i in m), **i** starts from index zero so **i** is the element of index 0 which its value is 0 then in for loop you'll delete zero value.

now your list is [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] and **i** is the element of index 1 which its value is 2.

after deleting 2 your list would be like [2,3,4,5,6,7], now **i** is the element of index 2 which its value is 4 and ....

here is how this for loop works and why the output is like that.

to remove all element in a list you can use:

```
for i in range(len(m)):
    m.remove(m[0])
```

or

```
m.clear()
```

Answer (score 1):

What happens here is, you're removing items in the list on the go.

Eg,

1. On the first remove() call, it removes 0 from the list (current
   index is 0).
2. On the second remove() call, the current index is 1,
   but the list contains [1,2,3,...]. Now the the index 1 contains "2"
   instead of "1". Because 0 has been removed and the size of list is
   just changed.

So to clear list in python, you can use,

```
m.clear()
```

Comment: Well wasn't the pop function work that way? Coz remove function has a syntax of List.remove(object). The remove functions will get objects and removes it. It works with objects but not index. So in the second iteration we get m.remove(1) and thus removing 1 from the list.

Comment: remove doesn't use index but the for loop uses. The for loop has current running index, it gives you elements based on indices.

Comment: Ohkk. I got what you are trying to say.

Answer (score -1):

i don`t know why it is not remove each item, but i worked on it and it works like this:

```
m=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
while m != []:
    [m.remove(i) for i in m]
print(m)
```

Comment: If you're going to do that you can skip the while loop and just write m=[]

Comment: Ok , `x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
for i in x[::]:
    x.remove(i)
print(x)`